# How to group my time by month / week in pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this DataFrame about my Facebook that says, the events I interested at, I joined and the respective time frame for them. I am having some problem of grouping the time by month or week, because there are two of them

```
    joined_time interested_time
0   2019-04-01  2019-04-21
1   2019-03-15  2019-04-06
2   2019-03-13  2019-03-26
```

Both time indicates when I clicked the 'Going' or 'Interested' button when an event pops up in Facebook. Sorry for the very small sample size, but this is what I have simplified it down to at the moment. And what I am trying to achieve here is that,

```
Year  Month    Total_Events_No    Events_Joined    Events_Interested
2019   3               3                  2                  1
       4               3                  1                  2
```

Where in this DataFrame, the year and month are multi-index, and the other columns consist of the counts of respective situations.

Comment: Try using **resample** function of pandas, it should give you some idea about your target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using `melt` before `groupby` and `unstack`

```
s=df.melt()
s.value=pd.to_datetime(s.value)
s=s.groupby([s.value.dt.year,s.value.dt.month,s.variable]).size().unstack()
s['Total']=s.sum(axis=1)
s
variable     interested_time  joined_time  Total
value value                                     
2019  3                    1            2      3
      4                    2            1      3
```

Comment: Dude, THIS IS CRAZY!!! Thank you so much!!! Man, I would like to know where do you get your practice from??? This few lines are so high level!! If I was to do it, it would've been 10 times more line than that.

Comment: @Alex_Zhong you can start with pandas cook book https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/cookbook.html. Also if this work for you, would you like accept it ? check mark at the left

Comment: Could you recommend the top 3 ways of learning and resources please?? And just read through the cookbook and code along with it, wouldn't be too effective right?

Comment: @Alex_Zhong there are some open courses on coursera; and some good book you can as reference https://books.google.com/books/about/Pandas_Cookbook.html?id=yRhKDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button#v=onepage&q&f=false